# Editing hosts file don't block ad from showing up

Tags: macos, networking, dns

I probably had some mis-understanding toward host files. so my understanding is that hosts file is the first priority DNS lookup place.

sometimes I will encounter some annoying websites like this one wo1.shouyoushe.com. I guess my ISP send that damn thing to me. so I just want to block anything from this place to show up on my computer. so I added this line to my hosts file on Mac

```
127.0.0.2   wo1.shouyoushe.com
```

just some address that don't exist. but after I flush the DNS cache, it is still there When I try to access it.

what is the issue ? is there a more appropriate way to do this on MAC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 127.0.0.1 which is localhost, i.e., 'me'

Also, flush DNS changed after 10.6 so it depends what OS you're on

10.6 or earlier

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
```

10.7 or later

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: bingo, I used the old command against 10.9 OSX. solved.